# PhoneGap Events Not Firing On iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, events, cordova, resume

I've started developing for iPhone using PhoneGap and an iPhone running iOS 5. With the following code, the deviceready and online events appear to fire when the application starts but none of the others, in particular, the resume / pause events appear to. I've tried using the menu button to close the app and then re-open it but nothing appears to fire the resume event.

If anyone could shed any light on this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener('pause', onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener('online', onOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', onOffline, false);
}

function onResume() {
    alert('resume');
}

function onPause() {
    alert('pause');
}

function onOnline() {
    alert('online');
}

function onOffline() {
    alert('offline');
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too. Which version of PhoneGap are you using? I'm on 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was an [ID10-T error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error): my PhoneGap app was redirecting to a URL which I had changed in one place but not in the other. The result was it looked like I was running my development code but I was actually running against a remote server running code without onResume and onPause events!

BTW, documentation for these events can be found at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_events_events.md.html